# Why is BART so good?

Tags: bayesian, causality, treatment-effect, bart

It seems that BART (bayesian additive regresssion trees) is a very widely and successfully used method for causal inference.

However this method was designed as a predictive method and does not explicitly account for any problems encountered in causal inference.

Are you familiar with any theoretical explanation or theorems proving why is BART such a successful method?

Comment: I'm not sure I have time to do a full answer on this, but the jist is that this is a really hard question to answer (i.e what does successful mean in what contexts etc.). The best formal attempt I am aware of is this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02641.pdf. But as someone in causal inference I can say this comes up and is debated regularly. Most people point to the importance of being able to flexibly model the outcome surface as a potential explanation, but this is certainly not the whole of it.

Comment: The reason why counterfactual regression should perform well is because it minimizes the IPM bound in the generalization bound they derive, or causal forest that is robust to confounding. But no such theoretical reason for BART.

Comment: (+1) Agreed with both comments. Ultimately, the answer *should* be that the regularisation performed by the prior approximates some metric that is related to counterfactual prediction; naively BART is good to HTE estimation because it doesn't "over-fit the ATE" during training (something that standard GBM would be more likely to do based on the use of residuals when computing the functional gradent) but that's really super-hand-wavy.