# How can I combined Bayesian and non-parametric techniques?

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric

I'd like to combine Bayesian and non-parametric (e.g. XGBoost) models, with the goal of getting a probability distribution over my target variable rather than a point estimate. I have a prior, and I have some non-parametric models that produce reasonable results. My best guess is something like fit a simple Bayesian regression model and use the non-parametric model estimates as inputs.

Is there a more effective or more principled way to do this though?

Comment: Possibly bootstrapping?  Could fit a variety of models on bootstrapped resamples of the data and report the distribution of predicted values.

Comment: Could you give us more details? What is the prior?

Comment: as @Arthur suggested, if what you are after is a probability of the target distribution then just run bootstrap samples.That is a principled, simple way of getting a probability distribution.

Comment: What about this: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v22/kim12/kim12.pdf ?

Comment: If you're looking for a Bayesian version of tree models, your answer is [BART](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/490882).